# Javascript webrtc group video streamming

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming

I would like to receive help to add group video streaming to the bellow code, i would like to implement a group streaming which ll be working with a link like

> domain.net/video.html?id=123&host=1 domain.net/video.html?id=456&host=1 to allow friends joining using param id.

```
'use strict';

// Put variables in global scope to make them available to the browser console.
const constraints = window.constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
    window.stream = stream;
    video.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
    if (error.name === 'ConstraintNotSatisfiedError') {
        const v = constraints.video;
        console.log("The resolution not supported");
    } else if (error.name === 'PermissionDeniedError') {
        console.log('Permissions have not been granted');
    }
    console.log(`getUserMedia error: ${error.name}`, error);
}

async function init(e) {
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        handleSuccess(stream);
        e.target.disabled = true;
    } catch (e) {
        handleError(e);
    }
}

document.querySelector('#showVideo').addEventListener('click', e => init(e));

Am in my learning stages to JavaScript please help, thanks.
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @lnogueir I wanted to stream video between two+ users. where param host=1 is the host of the video and the param id is the video url to be joined.

Comment: I know what you mean, but are you looking for code to do that or suggestions on how you would go about doing that?

Comment: I wanted the missing part of the code where possible. please.

Comment: There are many things missing in your script, so I don't think I would be able to add everything that's missing there. What I can do is provide you some sample code that you can refer to and some ideas on how to make it scalable, would that help?

Comment: That can help i hope they wont be links which i have visited already, despite this i have this https://github.com/nejat-njonjo/webrtc which is doing what i wanted but i don't need the registration or the login part, my assumption was to pick video link from my existing mysql database

Answer (score 1):

The script you provided currently gets the user camera and audio. You will need to feed that to an [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) and establish a WebRTC session with the other peers by exchanging SDP messages and ICE candidates via a signaling server. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Connectivity) to understand more in detail how WebRTC connectivity works.

Since you want to stream to a group of people, one approach is to create a new `RTCPeerConnection` for every new peer in your room. Check out this [example](https://github.com/lnogueir/webrtc-socketio-sample), it does exactly that.

However, since WebRTC is intended for peer-to-peer, this solution is not very scalable, because you are going to be creating new peer connections exponentially, which is quite heavy for the browser to handle and consumes a lot of bandwidth.
With +6 people, the quality of your call will already be terrible, but I think up to 4 people it should be doable.

If your intention is to have a conference room, you should really look into using a [Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU)](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) media server. With this approach, the server will perform stream routing and apply some tricks such as [Simulcast](https://webrtcglossary.com/simulcast/) to make your stream more scalable and adaptive, providing a better experience.

Checkout [Janus VideoRoom](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/videoroom.html) plugin for an open-source SFU implementation.

Comment: The git is not working, and other codes are in python .py, am going through the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection

Comment: Thanks for the info, i have gone through it and practice but i no lucky to get it right.